# ASP.net Core Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure AD for authentication in my ASP.net core app. I can retrieve a token from Azure using postman but when I go to make a request I get the following errror:

"Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid""

Setup.cs

```
namespace CoreDesk.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://sts.windows.net/7d63a3a5-79de-44c2-b5a3-ec21f4d24329/";
                options.Audience = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero;
            });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseCors(builder => builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .AllowAnyHeader());

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your valid audience should be your API's identifier. Not Microsoft's API's.

Comment: Hi Chris having exact same issue as you did you figure out how you solved it.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? Have the same (

Comment: view this link with the same doubut that i had. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74880940/validate-bearer-token-azure-ad-with-msal/74887902#74887902