# Validate Bearer token (azure ad) with MSAL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a aspnet core 6 API and i need in my controller of API, validated the bearer token that with Microsoft Authentication Libraries (MSAL).

I want verify in token, for example, my tenant or clientId.

How i do this simple? I need add notation to verify, for example [AuthorizeMSAL]?

Or i need to call "https://graph.microsoft.com" to validate token?

Example my code:

I receive an exception

The provided value for scope offline_access openid profile is not valid. Client credential flows must have a scope value with /.default suffixed to the resource identifier (application ID URI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if the **`scope`** value is invalid while generating the token.

**Note** that, Client Credential Grant Type accepts scope with **`./default`** or `api://ClientId/.default` only.

**To resolve the error**, use the parameters like below while generating the token:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
grant_type:client_credentials
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

***Access token generated successfully like below:***

[image]

To validate the Bearer token, use the below sample code in your **`_Startup.cs_`** file as mentioned in this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration#token-validation-in-azure-functions):

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration);
services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
  var existingOnTokenValidatedHandler = options.Events.OnTokenValidated;
  options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
  {
       await existingOnTokenValidatedHandler(context);
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers = new[] { Issuers };
      options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = new[] { valid};
  };
});
```

The **Bearer token will be validated** successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: Thank´s, i solved my error with this (scope  api://ClientId/.default).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for in here is the Microsoft Identity Platform, which does the job of handling Tokens and authorization in the Backend part (.net web APIs). In here I will suppose you have read and done the required configuration on the Azure portal, client app registration, API registration, and exposing API [(via scope or app roles)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration?view=aspnetcore-7.0#exposed-api) if not please refer to [the following docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-api-quickstart?pivots=devlang-aspnet) for that.

Then you will need to install [Microsoft.Identity.Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Web) NuGet package to be able to handle the token.In order to make use of the token you need to register the following authentication service to the container inside program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

At this point you should already have and Azure Ad section in your appsetting.json with details from you Azure AD configuration like mentioned below :

```
    {
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "Enter_the_Application_(client)_ID_here",
    "TenantId": "common",
    "Audience": "Enter_the_Application_ID_URI_here"
  },
}
```

If the configuration is done right in the Azure portal side, and you have the correct credentials at your appsettings.json, you should be able to allow only authenticated users into a specific controller by adding the **[Authorize]** annotation above the controller definition.

You find here [a link to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-api-quickstart?pivots=devlang-aspnet) mentioning all the steps, along with a sample that you can follow on. And [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration) contains more information about MSAL issued bearer token configuration and validation